# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, vars) is not working in Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, java-6

When using

```
final Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>(System.getenv());
env.put("ECLIPSE_PROJ_PATH", fileSelectedPath);
final String[] envVars = SystemUtils.mapToStringArray(env);
try {           

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/gedit",envVars).waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it  doesn't work an gedit doesn't show up and no exceptions occur.

but when removing the env vars and only use the command in exec method like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/gedit").waitFor();
```

it works correctly.

I need to have my env vars set while running my program.. 
note : this works fine on windows.

Comment: I'd recommend debugging into the code and checking which values are in `env` before you start the execution. Maybe there's something wrong with some value?

Comment: That's not how you pass Environment variables (e.g. `DISPLAY`). You're passing the environment variables as command line arguments. Also, you should probably use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Output the hashmap env - I would be interested to know what it contains.

Comment: what is the point of using waitFor() here ?

Comment: variables are correct. and process builder gives the same situation.

Comment: the map contains variables in format of "var=val1"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what SystemUtils.mapToStringArray returns, but it might be easier to use the ProcessBuilder, where environment variables can be provided in a Map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment()

Comment: Same situation happens. when I use process builder and add the env vars, it doesn't work. but when I run the command only without adding the variable it works

Comment: Have you attempted to read data from the process output? Is there anything returned from either [output stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) or [error stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream())?